# Editors that support Asp.NET MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, editor

Are there any editors except Visual Studio that support Razor syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're referring to "ASP.NET MVC Razor" but asking about an editor with Razor support so I'm not sure if you need MVC or you're just looking for Razor support. Razor isn't exclusive to ASP.NET MVC.

If you're just looking for Razor support, try Microsoft's new [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/). It's got a very nice feature set and it's free.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using Visual Studio because of the cost, try [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/). VS has the best Razor/MVC/.NET support. No reason not to use it IMO, it's a great IDE.

Comment: Each instance eats up 500 Mbs of RAM. Great IDE, poor text editor :-)